# C# AWS Lambda Reading Encrypted AWS S3 Excel to CSV (AES)

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aes, .net-6.0

We have some S3 buckets in AWS where we store csv files. These files are "encrypted" using our own routine (not truly an encryption, but I digress). Encryption on the buckets themselves is NOT enabled. When our Lambda's (which are built on c#/.NET 6) ingest the files from the buckets, we use AesManaged with our Secret/Salt to decrypt the file into a Stream. The Stream then gets copied over to a MemoryStream (utf8 encoded), which we then send up to another bucket (unecrypted) for further processing. This all works perfectly fine for these csv files.

Introduce the new ask to also support Excel files (xls, xlsx). We now need to be able to read the "encrypted" Excel file from S3, decrypt it, and ultimately get it to the MemoryStream for processing.

When I try to pass the Excel file through our existing code, it acts like it wants to work (no exceptions) but it doesn't actually decrypt anything. Temporarily, I wrote the "decrypted" MemoryStream to a temp bucket and looked at the file. It appeared to still be encrypted and FileExplorer warns that the file format and extension don't match.

Clearly I'm doing something wrong and/or missing something, but I cannot figure out what is missing or what path I need to go down. I have been unsuccessful in finding any relevant or working samples to start from. I have tried to first convert the file from Excel to csv, but had no luck with that either. We don't HAVE to convert the file from Excel to csv if we can decrypt it as-is, but we may still evaluate that need later.

Interested to see any thoughts or suggestions!

Here is the high-level process/methods we currently have:

```
var resultms = new MemoryStream();
var ddresult = DownloadAndDecrypt(s3client, bucketName, fileName, credInput);

if (ddresult.Stream != null)
{
     CopyStream(ddresult.Stream, resultms);
}

var encBytes = resultms.ToArray();
var encoding = Encoding.Default;
var sr = new StreamReader(resultms);
encoding = sr.CurrentEncoding;
var utf8Bytes = Encoding.Convert(encoding, Encoding.UTF8, encBytes);
var tempms = new MemoryStream(utf8Bytes);
sr.Close();

var s3uploadresult = WriteFileToS3(newBucketName, fileName, tempms, s3Client);


// Here are the methods referenced above
public StreamResultModel DownloadAndDecrypt(AmazonS3Client s3Client, string bucketName, string filename, CredInputModel credInput)
{

    var result = new StreamResultModel
    {
        Error = false
    };

    try
    {
        using var transferUtility = new TransferUtility(s3Client);
        var request = new TransferUtilityOpenStreamRequest
        {
            BucketName = bucketName,
            Key = filename,
        };
        result.Stream = transferUtility.OpenStream(request);

        using var aes = new AesManaged
        {
            BlockSize = 128,
            KeySize = 256,
            Mode = CipherMode.CBC,
            Key = Convert.FromBase64String(credInput.KeySharedSecret),
            IV = Convert.FromBase64String(credInput.Salt),
        };
        var decryptor = aes.CreateDecryptor();
        result.Stream = new CryptoStream(result.Stream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read);
        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

        result.Error = true;
        result.ErrorMsg = e.Message;
        return result;
    };
}

public static void CopyStream(Stream input, Stream output)
{
    var buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
    int read;

    while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
        output.Write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
    output.Position = 0;
}

private FileResultModel WriteFileToS3(string bucketName, string filename, MemoryStream ms, AmazonS3Client s3Client)
{
    var result = new FileResultModel();
    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    try
    {
        using var transferUtility = new TransferUtility(s3Client);
        var request = new TransferUtilityUploadRequest
        {
            BucketName = bucketName,
            Key = filename,
            InputStream = ms
        };

        transferUtility.Upload(request);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        result.Error = true;
        result.ErrorMsg = $"Error in upload: {e.Message}";
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Looks like I MAY have found my issue. It's that secondary encoding (from var encBytes... to sr.Close();). Still doing some additional testing and if that ends up being true, I'll answer my own question with the details.

Answer (score 0):

I jumped the gun just a little bit. After taking a break, I stopped focusing on the decryption and looked at how we are encoding the stream after pulling the decrypted data. When the file is an Excel format, we do not need to be doing the secondary encoding. Simply bypassing that for Excel did the trick.